# Pi zero w headless: Already setup and running. No HDMI option. Wifi password changed. How to connect again?

Tags: wifi, headless

I have a working pi zero w, already setup and running. BUT, the wifi password changed.

As a result, I'm unable to connect to it via SSH.

I don't have an HDMI adapter nor an HDMI compatible screen for that matter, only a laptop, a USB-C cable, as I'm away from home for a couple of weeks.

Here is what I attempted so far:

- Enabling SSH over cable (`dtoverlay=dwc2` in config.txt, `modules-load=dwc2,g_ether` in cmdline.txt, hello service on the laptop, ...) It failed, SSh never recognize the `[hostname].local`.
- Created a new wpa_supplicant.conf file on the root of the SD with the new info. Rebooted the pi. No change. Doesn't connect. wpa_supplicant.conf didn't disappear from the root, so it looks like it wasn't taken in consideration.

Aside from re-formatting and reinstalling the whole code from scratch (I have backup, just would rather save the 5h of install), anything else I can try?

`OS`: RASPBIAN STRETCH LITE Kernel 4.14

Comment: I had the same problem. What I did was I changed my wifi password to old password and connected again to my Pi ZERO and then in the config I gave the new password. It got disconnected but when I changed my wifi to the new password or the recent changed password it got connected again.

Comment: find an old router at a second-hand store ... i think that you know the rest ................. also, you may be able to set up a hotspot on your laptop instead

Comment: Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here. Could you please state which OS you are using. Assuming a current Raspbian it is indeed strange that it is not moving a new wpa_supplicant file from `/boot`.

Comment: I updated the post to include the OS version. It is indeed a current raspbian, the stretch lite.

Comment: Please do not post the answer as an edit to the question - post an answer instead. Thanks!

Comment: You're right, answer posted.

Answer (score 1):

Solved.

I hadn't noticed before that the green LED on the pi zero wasn't blinking at startup, but was staying a solid green, without any fluctuation in intensity.

I figured it must indicate some type of booting issue.

So I removed the cmdline.txt and the config.txt files from the root (which I had created in a failed attempt to activate SSH over cable), and it fixed the issue. The LED started blinking at startup, and my device finally appeared on the IP scanner.

Still no clue how to activate SSH over cable, but at least I can SSH into it via wifi now.